# Access Tomcat JNDI resource from object factory

Tags: tomcat, resources, jndi

I wrote a custom object factory to create a JNDI resource in Tomcat.

```xml
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
   factory="com.xxx.xxx.XXFactory" ... />
```

How can I access another JNDI resource from the same context in the object factory implementation?

Answer (score 1):

You can access JNDI from your object factory in the same way you would anywhere else:

```java
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
Object ref = ctx.lookup("path-to-JNDI-object");
```